# Notifications drawer or new page? Linkedin vs FB

Tags: notification

Most applications like Facebook show notifications in a notifications drawer. However, LinkedIn shows them on a new page. Why might taking the user to a whole new page be better UX than using a drawer/overlay pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm in favour of using notifications in a drawer or even a small dropdown with the latest 5-10 notifications.

**Why?**

Having notifications on a separate page has always annoyed me at Linkedin.
As a user, I don't want to interrupt what I'm doing, go check notifications and get back to what I was doing. I can get a lot of notifications on Linkedin and I don't always check them because I need to interrupt what I'm doing.